# Python: Sum values in DataFrame if other values match between DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, conditional-statements

I have two dataframes of different length like those:

DataFrame A:

```
FirstName    LastName
Adam         Smith
John         Johnson
```

DataFrame B:

```
First        Last        Value
Adam         Smith       1.2
Adam         Smith       1.5
Adam         Smith       3.0
John         Johnson     2.5
```

Imagine that what I want to do is to create a new column in "DataFrame A" summing all the values with matching last names, so the output in "A" would be:

```
FirstName    LastName    Sums
Adam         Smith       5.7
John         Johnson     2.5
```

If I were in Excel, I'd use

```
=SUMIF(dfB!B:B, B2, dfB!C:C)
```

In Python I've been trying multiple solutions but using both np.where, df.sum(), dropping indexes etc., but I'm lost. Below code is returning "ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects", but I don't think it's written correctly anyways.

```
df_a['Sums'] = df_a[df_a['LastName'] == df_b['Last']].sum()['Value']
```

Huge thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for filtering and then aggregate `sum`:

```
df = (df_b[df_b['Last'].isin(df_a['LastName'])]
           .groupby(['First','Last'], as_index=False)['Value']
           .sum())
```

If want match both, first and last name:

```
df = (df_b.merge(df_a, left_on=['First','Last'], right_on=['FirstName','LastName'])
           .groupby(['First','Last'], as_index=False)['Value']
           .sum())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) + [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
new_df=( dfa.merge(dfb.groupby(['First','Last'],as_index=False).Value.sum() ,
                   left_on='LastName',right_on='Last',how='left')
            .drop('Last',axis=1) )
print(new_df)
```

---

to join for both columns:

```
new_df=( dfa.merge(dfb.groupby(['First','Last'],as_index=False).Value.sum() ,
              left_on=['FirstName','LastName'],right_on=['First','Last'],how='left')
            .drop(['First','Last'],axis=1) )
print(new_df)
```

---

**Output:**

```
  FirstName LastName  Value
0      Adam    Smith    5.7
1      John  Johnson    2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_b_a = (pd.merge(df_b, df_a, left_on=['FirstName', 'LastName'], right_on=['First', 'Last'], how='left')
                .groupby(by=['First', 'Last'], as_index=False)['Value'].sum())

print(df_b_a)

    First   Last    Value
0   Adam    Smith   5.7
1   John    Johnson     2.5
```